# How do I prove that $\left|b_n-b\right|<\frac{|b|}{2} $ implies $\left|b_n\right|>\frac{|b|}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

It's a super important step in the Abbott Analysis book that:

$\left|b_n-b\right|<\frac{|b|}{2} $

implies

$\left|b_n\right|>\frac{|b|}{2}$

And I can't for the life of me figure how to prove it even though it's a simple step :( Tried the triangle inequality in 50 different configurations

When I draw it out with all the cases I get it, but I want to be able to prove it without considering all the positives and negative combinations separately

Comment: Does Abbott not talk about the “reverse” triangle inequality $$\left||x|-|y|\right|\le |x-y|?$$

Comment: Not really, mentioned in an even-numbered (no solution) exercise. But I couldn't figure it out even using that. How would you use the reverse triangle inequality to solve the equation above? @TedShifrin

Comment: $|b|-|b_n|<|b|/2$, so $|b|/2<|b_n|$. Totally equivalent to @Manifoldski’s proof (indeed, that proves the reverse triangle inequality).

Answer (score 2):

$$|b|\leq |b-b_{n}|+|b_{n}|<\frac{|b|}{2}+|b_{n}| \implies \frac{|b|}{2}<|b_{n}|$$

Comment: I like yours better. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Okay for some reason the ||≤|−_|+|_| part completely eluded me, maybe because I wouldn't have thought to expand it like that. Any tips on how I can think like that in the future? Because Abbott isn't even a hard text apparently and he just skipped over that part like it was trivial D:

Comment: I think it is just one of those tricks you see once and then you try to keep it in mind as you move forward. I recall using it quite a lot in introductory analysis so it sticks beyond pure memorization quite quickly. As for applying it here, I guess it's experience; You see "$|b|$" on the left and want a "$|b_{n}|$" on the right, so the trick comes to mind. It is also quite possible that this connection is made through the reverse triangle inequality, connecting $|b_{n}-b|$,$|b|$ and $|b_n|$, as mentioned by @TedShifrin.